# How can I optimize my syntax highlighting?

Tags: android, performance, syntax-highlighting, android-textwatcher

I am making a text editor in Android and I want to add syntax highlighting to it. With my current implementation, the UI is laggy when I type something. I need help with optimizing my current implementation.

```
private void onEditorListener() {

    edtEditor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do your actual work here
                    MaineActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    MaineActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textHighLighter(s);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 600);


        }

    });
}
```

```
private void textHighLighter(Editable s) {

    // Check the matcher for general keywords..
    Matcher a = Patterns.GENERAL_KEYWORDS.matcher(s.toString());
    // Check the matcher for html tags..
    Matcher b = Patterns.HTML_TAGS.matcher(s.toString());
    // Check the matcher for html attribute..
    Matcher c = Patterns.HTML_ATTRS.matcher(s.toString());
    // Check the matcher for symbol..
    Matcher d = Patterns.SYMBOLS.matcher(s.toString());
    // Check the matcher for general strings..
    Matcher e = Patterns.GENERAL_STRINGS.matcher(s.toString());
    // Find all the general key words and change the text color...
    // Find all the html tags words and change the text color...
    while (b.find()) {
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.orchid)), b.start(), b.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //android.util.Log.i("VINCE", b.toString());
    }

    while (a.find()) {
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.bounded)), a.start(), a.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //android.util.Log.i("VINCE", b.toString());
    }

    while (c.find()) {
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.henn)), c.start(), c.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //android.util.Log.i("VINCE", b.toString());
    }

    while (d.find()) {
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), d.start(), d.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //android.util.Log.i("VINCE", b.toString());
    }

    while (e.find()) {
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.general_str)), e.start(), e.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //android.util.Log.i("VINCE", b.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(2000);` no wonder it lags...

Comment: An actual answer might be too long for this format; in short you are trying to a background task the wrong way, you are starting a new timer task after every character is typed, and a proper highlighting function will distinguish between changed and unchanged test so it only needs to re-highlight changed text.

Comment: I put an thread because i want to pause immediately the effect of syntax highlighting then when it comes to more characters it edit text it becomes a loggy How can i optimize my edittext sir ?

Comment: any idea or format sir how can i optimize my edittext ?

Comment: sir what is your actual answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

Use a `Handler` and a `Runnable` instead of `TimerTask`. I'm assuming you want to wait n milliseconds before calling `textHighLighter(Editable s)` after `afterTextChanged(final Editable s)` is invoked. To do this, use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delay)` and `handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable)`.

Remove `Thread.sleep(2000)`.

An `Editable` extends `CharSequence`. Do no call `toString()` on your `Editable`, just pass it as an argument to `Pattern#matcher(CharSequence)`.

Comment: thank you for your response sir  ! I will try it your idea i hope this will work for me thanks :D

Comment: Hello sir i try it it becomes laggy again I put the runnable in aftertextchanged and call the textHighLighter method

Answer (score 0):

```
@Jared Rummler here is my code

@Overrideenter code here
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                last_text_edit = System.currentTimeMillis();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, idle_min);
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= (last_text_edit + idle_min - 500)) {
                                // user hasn't changed the EditText for longer than
                                // the min delay (with half second buffer window)

                                textHighLighter(s);  // your queries
                                if (!already_queried) { // don't do this stuff twice.
                                    already_queried = true;
                                    //textHighLighter(s);  // your queries
                                    android.util.Log.i("VINCE", "already_queried");
                                }
                            }

                            //already_queried = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                            android.util.Log.i("VINCE", "Cancelled");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };
```